# Error when calling h2o.init() in R to connecting to remote cluster

Tags: r, amazon-ec2, h2o

I'm trying to connect to the cluster hosted on EC2 machine from R and getting the same error when trying both on Windows and Mac:

```
> h2o.init(ip = "<Public IP>")
 Connection successful!


ERROR: Unexpected HTTP Status code: 404 Not Found (url = http://<Public IP>:54321/3/Cloud?skip_ticks=true)

Error: lexical error: invalid char in json text.
                                       <!DOCTYPE html> <html lang="en"
                     (right here) ------^
```

- Cluster is reachable at `http://<Public IP>:54321/`
- Starting a local cluster with `h2o.init()` also works fine in R, so the problem is only when trying to connect to **remote** one.

I've seen the following [issue](https://0xdata.atlassian.net/browse/PUBDEV-1460) marked as resolved, but it doesn't help in my case. Have anybody experienced anything similar?

---

**UPD:** The answer was very simple. It turns out that the code example given in their [guide for EC2](http://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/rel-lambert/5/docs-website/deployment/ec2_build_ami.html) is outdated and uses the old version of H2O. Using the most recent version ([3.9.1.5555](http://s3.amazonaws.com/h2o-release/h2o/master/3555/index.html) at the moment) on EC2 machines has resolved the issue.

Comment: Are you sure that the h2o R package you have locally and the H2O cluster you are running remotely are the same version?

Comment: This is useful, but instead of editing your question with the answer, you should answer your own question and accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To elaborate on the OP's update, when using a remote cluster:

Make sure you install the most recent version (check the [S3 download page](http://s3.amazonaws.com/h2o-release/h2o/master/latest.html) for the redirect to the release number).  In the example below, this is 3.13.0.3908:

```
wget http://s3.amazonaws.com/h2o-release/h2o/master/3908/h2o-3.13.0.3908.zip
unzip h2o-3.13.0.3908.zip
mv h2o-3.13.0.3908 h2o
cd h2o
java -Xmx4g -jar h2o.jar
```

You then need to install the version of `h2o-R` that corresponds to this version.  (The correct version is likely **not the CRAN version**.)  Otherwise you will get an error like:

```
Error in h2o.init(ip = "XXX.XX.XX.XXX", startH2O = FALSE) : 
  Version mismatch! H2O is running version 3.13.0.3908 but h2o-R package is version 3.10.4.6.
         Install the matching h2o-R version from - http://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/master/3908/index.html
```

So you need to note the version number H2O is running (in the above example, 3908), make sure you have previously removed any existing `h2o-R` package (see [here](http://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/master/3908/index.html) for more info), and then do:

```
install.packages("h2o", type="source", repos="http://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/master/3908/R")
```

Now it should work:

```
library('h2o')
remoteH2O <- h2o.init(ip='XXX.XX.XX.XXX', startH2O=FALSE) #  Connection successful!
```